# jsdom's getVirtualConsole example

Tags: javascript, console.log, jsdom

I'm trying to `console.log("hello world")` from [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom)'s `getVirtualConsole` function. I'm not getting any response.

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom")
var window = jsdom.jsdom('<html><body><script type="text/javascript">console.log(\"hello world\")</script></body></body>').defaultView;
jsdom.getVirtualConsole(window).sendTo(console);
```

This is basically pulled straight from [the documentation](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom#capturing-console-output).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your script is running before you can even get the virtual console. If you delayed it a bit, you would see the output.

However, this is obviously a pretty problematic situation to be in. So we added [a new API](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom#forward-a-windows-console-output-to-the-iojs-console) in 5.3.0 that allows you to create a virtual console ahead of time, and pass it in. Thus, you can do

```
"use strict";
const jsdom = require("jsdom");

const virtualConsole = jsdom.createVirtualConsole();
virtualConsole.sendTo(console);

const window = jsdom.jsdom(`
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <script>console.log("hello world");</script>`,
    { virtualConsole }).defaultView;
```

Comment: `const virtualConsole = new jsdom.VirtualConsole();` since JDOM version 10